# At "@" symbol on Swedish keyboard layout stopped working?

Tags: macos, keyboard

On macOS Monterey, the Swedish Pro keyboard has disappeared and in the default layout (Swedish), the 'at' symbol doesn't work.

While checking with the keyboard viewer, I noticed that the keyboard shortcuts `Option + 1` to `Option + 5` doesn't work. Anyone found a way around?